# Technique to simplify algebraic calculations on roots of polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

I was once told about a technique to simplify algebra on the roots of a polynomial.
So if you want to find $\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3$, where $\alpha,\beta \text{ and } \gamma$ are roots of $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, then you find a new quadratic with its roots as $\alpha^3, \beta^3 \text{ and } \gamma^3$ or something like that(I don't remember exactly). Does somebody know what this technique exactly is?

---

**Note: Please modify the question title and details as necessary.**

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\alpha^3+\beta^3=(\alpha+\beta)^3-3\alpha\beta(\alpha+\beta)$$

$$\alpha^3\beta^3=(\alpha\beta)^3$$

---

Alternatively,
$$ax^2+bx+c=0\implies ax^2+bx=-c\implies (ax^2+bx)^3=(-c)^3$$

$$a^3(x^3)^2+b^3(x^3)+3ab(x^3)(-c)=-c^3$$

Replace $x^3$ with $y$ and rearrange

Comment: I know that...But it would get harder to do this when power is more...I want to instead know the technique of forming a new quadratic related to what we want to find

Comment: @shauryagupta, Find the edited version

Comment: It's still not what the technique was. you don't have to rearrange the given equation. It really simplified things a lot...You need to make a completely new quadratic.

Comment: What if I were to find $\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3$ in $t^3-9t^2+26t-24$?

Comment: @shauryagupta, I think this comment was meant for http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806201/number-of-solutions-to-the-equations-x-2y-4z-9-4yz-2xz-xy-13-xyz and the solution pattern can be http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806261/prove-3-3-s3-3ps-in-quadratic-equation/806290#806290

Comment: No, this comment is meant to be here. And the technique I'm looking for is very useful for this. what would be an equation whose roots are $\alpha^3, \beta^3 \text{ and } \gamma^3$?

Comment: @shauryagupta, But $\gamma$ is not defined in the Question, itself?

Comment: It is the third root of the cubic polynomial $t^3 - 9t^2 + 26t - 24$.

Comment: @shauryagupta, Where is the cubic Polynomial ?

Comment: It's $t^3−9t^2+26t−24$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14701/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-shaurya-gupta).

Answer (score 0):

The following computes powers of roots of quadratic equations very efficiently.  It can easily be extended to equations of higher degree.  Let $\alpha$ be a root of $$X^2+a X + b.$$

In the basis $\langle 1, \alpha\rangle$ multiplication by $\alpha$ in the field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ has matrix

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&-b\\1&-a\end{pmatrix}.$$

Powers of $\alpha$ can be expressed in this basis by taking the same power of $A$. The coefficients of $1$ and $\alpha$ are then given by the first column of the result. Powers of $A$ can be computed by the [repeated squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) method. For example, consider the quadratic $X^2-X-1$. Then $$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}.$$ To compute $\alpha^{10}$ first compute $$A^{10}=\begin{pmatrix}34&55\\55&89\end{pmatrix}.$$
Now the first column shows that $\alpha^{10}=55\alpha+34$. If $\beta$ is the other root then the same argument shows that $\beta^{10}=55\beta+34$. Then

$$\begin{eqnarray}\alpha^{10}+\beta^{10}&=&55(\alpha+\beta)+68=123\\
\alpha^{10}\beta^{10}&=&(\alpha \beta)^{10}=1
\end{eqnarray}$$

and $\alpha^{10}$, $\beta^{10}$ are roots of $X^2-123 X+1$.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are looking for [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Mathematical_statement).
These are the general form of lab's answer.  In particular you can [express power sums directly in terms of the coefficients of the polynomial.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Expressing_power_sums_in_terms_of_elementary_symmetric_polynomials)

Comment: please see my updated question.

Comment: 7 years later I found this answer extremely useful.

Comment: @arthur Good to hear! :)

Answer (score 0):

New question $\rightarrow$ new answer.  If $\alpha$, $\beta$ are the roots of $X^2+a X+ b$ then a polynomial expression $P(\alpha, \beta)$ can be reduced to a linear expression in $\alpha$ and $\beta$: First eliminate powers of $\alpha \beta = b$ from each monomial. Then use the technique from my other answer to reduce the remaining powers of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. This results in $$P(\alpha, \beta) = c_0 + c_1\alpha + c_2\beta$$ for some coefficients $c_0, c_1, c_2$. The quadratic for $P(\alpha, \beta)$ becomes $$(X-c_0)^2+a(c_1+c_2)(X-c_0) +a^2 c_1 c_2+b\, (c_1-c_2)^2.$$

Alternatively use Gröbner basis reduction on the ideal $$\langle X+Y+a, XY-b, P(X,Y)-Z \rangle$$ with $Z < X \wedge Y$ in the monomial order to find a quadratic equation in $Z$ alone. As an example consider $X^2-X-1$ and $P(\alpha, \beta) = 2\alpha + \beta$. Since this is already linear the formula above results in the following quadratic for $P(\alpha, \beta)$:

$$X^2-3X+1.$$

The same result using Gröbner basis reduction can be found [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=groebner+basis+%7Bx%2By-1%2C+x+y+%2B+1%2C+2x%2By-z%7D).