# Number of solutions to the equations $x + 2y + 4z = 9\\4yz + 2xz + xy = 13\\ xyz = 3$

Tags: linear-algebra

The number of solutions $(x, y, z)$ to the system of equations $$x + 2y + 4z = 9\\4yz + 2xz + xy = 13\\ xyz = 3$$ 
such that at least two of $x, y, z$ are integers is :

I am not sure where to begin even. The degree of all three equations is different and the added condition does not make it any easier. Please help

Comment: Hint:use vieta's formula

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$x,2y,4z$$ are the roots of $$t^3-9t^2+2\cdot13t-8\cdot3=0$$ of which $2$ is a root(by observation)

So, the rest two will be the roots of $$\frac{t^3-9t^2+26t-24}{t-2}=0$$

Answer (score 2):

If you need all variables to be integers, the last equation has rather few solutions.  One has to be $\pm 3$ and the others $\pm 1$ with a proper combination of signs.  So try them all.